# payu web-hooks failed due to django referer check

Tags: python, django, payu

I am integrating payu web-hooks on my django project . there are total four callbacks events from payu side i.e. success , dispute , failure and refund . Each callback is sending POST request to the django backend . The problem is occurring when i handle any callback event , django requires the csrf token which is missing inside payu request body so i added @csrf_exempt to bypass it and it worked , but after two or three requests , django starts to reject with the error message called 'Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.): /payu/success/'

After a bit of research i found that there is something called csrf-trusted-origins in django where i can add payu origins ... but unfortunately i didn't any help here too . any help will be appreciated ... thanks .